# excel to split data after comma and before space

Tags: excel-2010

I want to get the first name and middle name from cell. I am able to get the first name with the excel formula:

```
=LEFT(D2,FIND(",",D2)-1)
```

The name i.e `Shukla,Vinay Devanand` is reflecting in cell and I am able to get `Shukla` with above formula and now want only `Vinay` (All the characters after first comma and before first space)

Please help with the formula.

Comment: I got the solution. I am using text to column to split the name into first name, second name and last name. See below coding.......Dim objRange1 As Range
    Dim objRange2 As Range
    Set objRange1 = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lst)
    'Set objRange2 = Range("AN2:AN" & lst)

    objRange1.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Sheet2.Range("AM2"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=True, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=False, _
      OtherChar:="-"

Answer (score 0):

`Vinay` can be extracted by applying what is essentially the same process (replacing space for `,` however) on what is left once one more character (the `,`) is added to the length of what is already known (`Shukla`) and used as the start point:

```
=LEFT(MID(D2,LEN(LEFT(D2,FIND(",",D2)))+1,LEN(D2)),FIND(" ",MID(D2,LEN(LEFT(D2,FIND(",",D2)))+1,LEN(D2))))
```